# Dynamic SQL SELECT INTO returns dreaded ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Tags: oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql, execute-immediate, select-into

I am executing the following dynamic statement and receiving the ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended:

```
FUNCTION IsValidArchive RETURN BOOLEAN
IS        
    x   BOOLEAN := TRUE;
    isValidArc_sql VARCHAR2(2000);
BEGIN
    isValidArc_sql := 'SELECT COUNT(*), SUM(AMOUNT) ' ||
                      'FROM ' || srcSchemaTable ||
                      ' WHERE TRUNC( ' || parm_rec.SRC_DATE_COLUMN || ' ) < ADD_MONTHS( ' ||
                                                      'ADD_MONTHS ( TRUNC (  NVL ( TO_DATE ( :parm_rec.SYS_OFFSET ) , SYSDATE) - ( :parm_rec.DAY_OFFSET )), ' ||
                                                      '( :parm_rec.MON_OFFSET * :kNEGATIVE ) ), ' ||
                                                      '( :parm_rec.YR_OFFSET * ( :kANNUM * :kNEGATIVE ) ) ); ';                                                                                                                                               
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE isValidArc_sql
    INTO arc_cnt, arc_amt
    USING parm_rec.SYS_OFFSET, parm_rec.DAY_OFFSET, parm_rec.MON_OFFSET, kNEGATIVE, parm_rec.YR_OFFSET, kANNUM;

    IF arc_cnt > 0 AND arc_amt > 0 
        THEN x := TRUE;
    ELSE 
        x := FALSE;
    END IF;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'IsValidArchive: ' || CHR(10) ||
                          'Record Count - '  || arc_cnt || CHR(10) ||
                          'Total Amount - '  || arc_amt || CHR(13) );
    RETURN x;        
END IsValidArchive;
```

If I remove the WHERE clause this code will execute which makes me believe that this might be a bind variable issue. Having said that, I am using this very same WHERE clause (minus one bind variable here) in another part of the program without error.

My bind variables are all populating with the appropriate values, and my literals in the statement appear correct as well.

My research has revealed this syntax to be correct. I feel that the issue is in the WHERE, likely the bind variables, but the solution has yet to reveal itself. This code errors out on the EXECUTE IMMEDIATE statement.

I would be very grateful if someone could point out what I am doing wrong here.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

Thank you to Kris and Alex for pointing out the flaws in my code, below is the corrected code:

```
FUNCTION IsValidArchive RETURN BOOLEAN
IS        
    x   BOOLEAN := TRUE;
BEGIN
    isValidArc_sql := 'SELECT COUNT(*), SUM(AMOUNT) ' ||
                      'FROM ' || srcSchemaTable ||
                      ' WHERE TRUNC( createdate ) < ADD_MONTHS( ' ||
                                                      'ADD_MONTHS ( TRUNC (  NVL  ( :SYS_OFFSET  , SYSDATE ) - ( :DAY_OFFSET )), ' ||
                                                      '( :MON_OFFSET * :kNEGATIVE ) ), ' ||
                                                      '( :YR_OFFSET * ( :kANNUM * :kNEGATIVE ) ) ) ';                                                                                                                                               
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE isValidArc_sql
    INTO arc_cnt, arc_amt
    USING parm_rec.SYS_OFFSET, parm_rec.DAY_OFFSET, parm_rec.MON_OFFSET, kNEGATIVE, parm_rec.YR_OFFSET, kANNUM, kNEGATIVE;

    IF arc_cnt > 0 AND arc_amt > 0
        THEN x := TRUE;
    ELSE 
        x := FALSE;
    END IF;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'IsValidArchive: ' || CHR(10) ||
                          'Record Count - '  || arc_cnt || CHR(10) ||
                          'Total Amount - '  || arc_amt || CHR(13) );
    RETURN x;        
END IsValidArchive;
```

Comment: You have a trailing ; inside the quoted sql. nuke that

Comment: Thanks Kris that was part of the issue. Now I am getting a PL/SQL ORA-01008 : Not all variables bound message? All of my bind variables are used and populated?

Comment: Scratch that, receiveing ORA-22806: not an object or REF.

Answer (score 2):

As @KrisRice pointed out, you should not have the trailing semicolon in the dynamic statement. That is a client-defined statement separator and/or terminator in SQL*Plus etc., but this is a different context - you can only have one statement in a dynamic call, so it has no meaning.

You are then binding slightly incorrectly. You seem to think you need the bind variable name to match the name of the variable in the `using` clause, so you have things like `:parm_rec.SYS_OFFSET`. The bind variable name here is actually just the `parm_rec` part. And remember the generated statement is being executed in a SQL context, not a PL/SQL context, so the period is interpreted as part of the schema.object.column pattern, which doesn’t make sense when the first part - before the period - is a variable.

The `:parm_rec` bind variable *name* has nothing to do with the `parm_rec` PL/SQL record name. You could equally (in)validly have used `:b0.SYS_OFSET`, which perhaps makes the confusion clearer. `:b0` is not an object or a ref, hence the ORA-22806.

So, change the `:record.field` style references to simple identifiers, which can still have some nominal relationship to the matching variables, something like:

```
    isValidArc_sql := 'SELECT COUNT(*), SUM(AMOUNT) ' ||
                      'FROM ' || srcSchemaTable ||
                      ' WHERE TRUNC( ' || parm_rec.SRC_DATE_COLUMN || ' ) < ADD_MONTHS( ' ||
                                                      'ADD_MONTHS ( TRUNC (  NVL ( TO_DATE ( :SYS_OFFSET ) , SYSDATE) - ( :DAY_OFFSET )), ' ||
                                                      '( :MON_OFFSET * :kNEGATIVE ) ), ' ||
                                                      '( :YR_OFFSET * ( :kANNUM * :kNEGATIVE ) ) ) ';                                                                                                                                               
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE isValidArc_sql
    INTO arc_cnt, arc_amt
    USING parm_rec.SYS_OFFSET, parm_rec.DAY_OFFSET, parm_rec.MON_OFFSET, kNEGATIVE, parm_rec.YR_OFFSET, kANNUM, kNEGATIVE;
```

I've also added the missing bind variable, repeating `kNEGATIVE` at the end, as these are referenced by position rather than by name. (You've presumably already fixed that yourself; you referred to the ORA-01008 that causes in a comment).

---

Presumably those bound values and all the other variables are coming from package-level variables since they aren’t defined in the function, which is fine if a little confusing without that context. (And presumably makes your package stateful, which can be a bit of a pain sometimes). It looks like at least `arc_cnt` and `arc_amt` are probably local though, so need to be declared? And maybe some or all of the others; it depends on other code we can't see.

Incidentally, it’s not a good idea to use `to_date()` without specifying a format mask, as it will rely on the client’s NLS settings. (And if that record field is already a date type, you shouldn’t be converting it at all.)

Comment: Thanks for your input Alex. I'm away from my computer for the evening so I will be sure to make the changes you suggest to see if that clears the errors I'm receiving. I'm new to dynamic SQL and learning the nuances. Thank you again for your input I'll update tomorrow with results.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help Alex! Indeed, you were correct regarding the bind variables and the use of the schem.object.column notation. The arc_cnt and arc_amt variables are declared gloabally in the package spec. Also, thank you for pointing out the TO_DATE() conversion, at one point I did have the date coming in as a string, but I altered the datatype to be of date-type, and have removed the conversion. Thank you very much for your help, your comments and suggestions are very informative!--Please see OP for update.